# Edit multiple objects in Play framework

Tags: playframework-2.1

The problem I'm facing is the following:
I have multiple rows in a table which have some common properties. I would like to be able to select multiple rows and populate their common parameters in a single entry.
I'm thinking of defining two models that describe a row together, a CommonRowModel that contains the properties that are commonly repeatable and SpecificRowModel that extends the CommonRowModel and is unique.
Is this the right way to go or there is a more elegant solution prowided by the Play Framework?

Comment: Let me understand: do you want to update many DB rows, the same way as it was written with native SQL `UPDATE my_table SET x=1 WHERE y=2` ?

Comment: BTW, tag the question with proper version of Play and used ORM (also describe it in the question)

Comment: The data is acquired from a device via a communication protocol (IEC61850) on demand, and after manipulation it is stored in a proprietary DB.
An in-memory DB will be used for simpler manipulation of data and I am planning to use the default in-memory DB provided with the framework.
In regards to the first question, yes I would like to do just that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your table will be probably relatively simple and flat (without relations, constraints etc) you can do it quite easy with [SqlUpdate](http://www.avaje.org/static/javadoc/pub/com/avaje/ebean/SqlUpdate.html) as showed in documentation:

```
String s = "UPDATE f_topic set post_count = :count where id = :id"
SqlUpdate update = Ebean.createSqlUpdate(s);
update.setParameter("id", 1);
update.setParameter("count", 50);

int modifiedCount = Ebean.execute(update);
```